# Returning Type SqlDataReader even when try catch fails - getting not all paths return a value

Tags: c#, .net-core

I'm trying to read from a DB with a try/catch and I want to obviously return data. I'm getting a message saying `not all code paths return a value`. I get that I need to return something, but how should I handle this scenario? Can I return an empty `SqlDataReader` object?

The stored procedures being run will return different types of objects depending on what's executed, otherwise I would return the specific type.

```
    private SqlDataReader RunSql(string connectionString, string procName)
    {
        using(SqlConnection = conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        { 
            using(SqlCommand SqlCmd = new SqlCommant(procName, conn))
            { 
                SqlCmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                conn.Open();

                try 
                {
                    using(SqlDataReader reader = SqlCmd.ExecuteReader())
                    {
                        if(reader.HasRows)
                        {  
                             return reader;
                        }
                    }
                }
                catch(Exception e)
                {
                    //?
                }
                finally
                {
                    conn.Close();

                }
            } 
        }
        //?
    }
```

Comment: Yes, because your method doesn't return anything if condition fails. So you could `return null` on  your commented line.

Comment: wow, i feel stupid now. I didn't even think to try that, but in hindsight that seems obvious. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As the method doesn't return anything if the condition failed this is the reason you are getting that compile error. You could try bellow snippet. Just `return null` on your commented line `//?`

```
private SqlDataReader RunSql(string connectionString, string procName)
        {

            using (var conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
            {
                using (SqlCommand SqlCmd = new SqlCommand(procName, conn))
                {
                    SqlCmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                    conn.Open();

                    try
                    {
                        using (SqlDataReader reader = SqlCmd.ExecuteReader())
                        {
                            if (reader.HasRows)
                            {
                                return reader;
                            }

                        }
                    }
                    catch (Exception e)
                    {

                    }
                    finally
                    {
                       conn.Close();

                    }
                }
            }
            return null;
        }
```

Hope that might resolve your compile error.

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer will work but, as written, it "swallows" the exception that you caught; this prevents the caller from even knowing that something went awry. A much better approach is to rethrow the exception so that the caller is still informed that something bad happened and then they can then deal with the issue however they want to.

Another issue is that the reader and connection objects will be disposed of before you ever consume them in downstream code; thanks to the `using` and `finally` statements. One solution to this issue is to make it the responsibility of the caller to handle the connection object.

```
private static SqlDataReader RunSql(SqlConnection connection, string procedureName) {
    using (var command = connection.CreateCommand()) {
        command.CommandText = procedureName;
        command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

        try {
            if (connection.State != ConnectionState.Open) {
                connection.Open();
            }

            var reader = command.ExecuteReader();

            if (reader.HasRows) {
                return reader;
            }
            else {
                return null;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            // log the exception or whatever you wanna do with it

            throw; // rethrow the exception
        }
    }
}
```

Here's an alternative version that uses `IAsyncEnumerable`; notice that we're now allowed to dispose of the objects within the same method. Also, the logic that handled the empty reader case is no longer required as our enumerable will simply be empty if there was nothing to read.

```
// define a container for information relevant to each row
public sealed class SqlResultSetRow : IEnumerable<(string fieldName, Type fieldType, object fieldValue)>
{
    private readonly (string fieldName, Type fieldType, object fieldValue)[] m_fields;

    public int ResultSetIndex { get; }

    public SqlResultSetRow((string, Type, object)[] fields, int resultSetIndex) {
        m_fields = fields;

        ResultSetIndex = resultSetIndex;
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator() => GetEnumerator();

    public IEnumerator<(string fieldName, Type fieldType, object fieldValue)> GetEnumerator() {
        var rows = m_fields;

        foreach (var row in rows) {
            yield return row;
        }
    }
    public object GetFieldName(int fieldOffset) => m_fields[fieldOffset].fieldName;
    public object GetFieldValue(int fieldOffset) => m_fields[fieldOffset].fieldValue;
}

// define a class to hold our generic method(s)
public static class SqlClientExtensions
{
    // implement a refactored version of the original method
    public static async IAsyncEnumerable<T> ProcessRows<T>(this SqlCommand command, Func<SqlResultSetRow, CancellationToken, ValueTask<T>> rowCallback, CommandBehavior commandBehavior = CommandBehavior.SequentialAccess, [EnumeratorCancellation] CancellationToken cancellationToken = default) {
        using (var dataReader = await command.ExecuteReaderAsync(commandBehavior, cancellationToken)) {
            var resultSetIndex = 0;

            do {
                var fieldCount = dataReader.FieldCount;
                var fieldNames = new string[fieldCount];
                var fieldTypes = new Type[fieldCount];

                for (var i = 0; (i < fieldCount); ++i) {
                    fieldNames[i] = dataReader.GetName(i);
                    fieldTypes[i] = dataReader.GetFieldType(i);
                }

                while (await dataReader.ReadAsync(cancellationToken)) {
                    var fields = new (string, Type, object)[fieldCount];

                    for (var i = 0; (i < fieldCount); ++i) {
                        fields[i] = (fieldNames[i], fieldTypes[i], dataReader.GetValue(i));
                    }

                    yield return await rowCallback(new SqlResultSetRow(fields, resultSetIndex), cancellationToken);
                }
            } while (await dataReader.NextResultAsync(cancellationToken));
        }
    }
}

class Program
{
    // a minimal implementation of a rowCallBack function
    public static async ValueTask<ExpandoObject> OnProcessRow(SqlResultSetRow resultSetRow, CancellationToken cancellationToken) {
        var rowValue = (new ExpandoObject() as IDictionary<string, object>);

        foreach (var field in resultSetRow) {
            rowValue[field.fieldName] = field.fieldValue;
        }

        return (rowValue as ExpandoObject);
    }

    // put everything together
    static async Task Main(string[] args) {
        try {
            var programTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(3);
            var cancellationTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource(programTimeout);

            using (var connection = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB;Initial Catalog=master;Integrated Security=True;"))
            using (var command = connection.CreateCommand()) {
                command.CommandText = "select 1 as [a];";
                command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

                await connection.OpenAsync(cancellationToken: cancellationTokenSource.Token);

                await foreach (dynamic row in command.ProcessRows(rowCallback: OnProcessRow, cancellationToken: cancellationTokenSource.Token)) {
                    Console.WriteLine($"a: {row.a}");
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            // do something with exception here

            throw;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: maybe you just want to log the exception and allow the app to keep going...

Comment: OP's concern was not in exception block but in outside of using block which has not been resolved on your code as well.

Comment: @MdFaridUddinKiron You're not wrong, I wrote the code entirely in the SO editor and missed the section where control flow escaped the `try` block. Also noticed that the OP had the reader wrapped in a `using`, this will cause the object to be disposed as soon as the method returns; just fixed both issues.

Comment: But still your code doesn't sounds elegant since if the condition fails you are also returning `null` I did it before but then I rigid on OP's code. Hope you understand.

Comment: @MdFaridUddinKiron I'm sorry, you lost me somewhere; the only time my example returns `null` is if the reader is empty. Personally, I don't think such a design is very useful but it seemed to be what the OP was going for. I believe that my second example is a much more elegant approach that still captures the spirit of what the OP was trying to do.

Comment: First of all the approach of questions is not best practice at all, I spent few times as op were stuck in rather teaching him best approach. Anyway your second approach is better than first one.

Comment: @JonathanAlfaro Sure, wanting that is a fine thing, but should such logic be encoded in a method that is clearly meant to be generic? Probably not...

Answer (score -2):

```
        { 
            SqlCmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            conn.Open();

            try 
            {
                using(SqlDataReader reader = SqlCmd.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    if(reader.HasRows)
                    {  
                         return reader;
                    }
                }
```